# Can s3 object metadata be safelly mapped to dynamodb using hash + bucketName + s3Key as partition key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Here is [dynamodb restrictions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html):

- partition key is 2048 bytes max
- sort key is 1024 bytes max

Here is s3 naming limit:

- [bucket restrition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) - 255 characters
- key - 1024 bytes.

The goal is creation s3 document to dynamodb table mapping. What if use hash + bucketName + s3Key as partition key?

```
var path = bucketName + "/" + s3Key
var primaryKey = SHA1(path) + path
```

Using `SHA1` as prefix gets me primary key randomization for scalling if s3 does not already have it. `bucketName` and `s3Key` gives me uniques. Also by `bucketName` and `s3key` I can generate id at any part of code without scan and/or query request.

About limit SHA1  reuiqres 42 characters, `bucketName` + `s3Key` = 255 + 1024 = 1279. So total SHA1, bucketName and s3Key fits well into dynamodb key limits.

The design look very well and so obvious but I have not seen that it is used. Am I miss somethings? Can such approach leads to performance issues or not?

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm should be fine.  Verify that SHA1 is sufficiently fast in your target environment.  If not, MD5 would also be suitable for this purpose, since you are concatenating the bucket and path and using the hash to provide better key distribution, not uniqueness, so you have no hash collision concerns.

Note That SHA1, hex-encoded, is only 40 bytes, not 42.

Note also that the recommended practice for S3 is for bucket names not to exceed 63 bytes.  Only the us-east-1 region has the relaxed limit of 255 bytes, for legacy reasons.